# Contract not compiling. "Failed to resolve: use of undeclared type `SecretKey`

Tags: ink, smart-contract, error, cargo

Here are the steps i have done:

1. cargo contract new flipper
2. in contract code i added these lines of code:
3. `use blst::min_pk::SecretKey;` after `#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]`
   & changed this function:

   ```
   #[ink(message)]
   pub fn flip(&mut self) {
       let ikm = [0u8; 32];
       let sk = SecretKey::key_gen(&ikm,&[]).unwrap();
       ink_env::debug_print!("{:?}",sk);
       self.value = !self.value;
   }
   ```
4. Run command cargo add blst
5. After the completion, my Cargo.toml file changed dependencies by adding

   blst = "0.3.10"
6. When i run: cargo+nightly contract build, i got error and warning:
   [image]
7. SecretKey is a struct that can be found in blst::min_pk directory. Its a dependence that can be found on github. I can link it if need.

Any help how do i fix this error? If you need more information, just tell me and i will provide!

Here is full Cargo.toml:
here is full Cargo.toml :

```
[package]
name = "testX"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["[your_name] <[your_email]>"]
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
ink_primitives = { version = "3.3", default-features = false }
ink_metadata = { version = "3.3", default-features = false, features = ["derive"], optional = true }
ink_env = { version = "3.3", default-features = false }
ink_storage = { version = "3.3", default-features = false }
ink_lang = { version = "3.3", default-features = false }

scale = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
scale-info = { version = "2", default-features = false, features = ["derive"], optional = true }
blst = "0.3.10"

[lib]
name = "testX"
path = "lib.rs"
crate-type = [
    # Used for normal contract Wasm blobs.
    "cdylib",
]

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "ink_metadata/std",
    "ink_env/std",
    "ink_storage/std",
    "ink_primitives/std",
    "scale/std",
    "scale-info/std",
]
ink-as-dependency = []
```

Comment: can you add `Cargo.toml` as well?

Comment: added in question!

Answer (score 1):

this specific error  display if you are adding `use blst::min_pk::SecretKey;` outside mod instead put inside `mod flipper { use blst::min_pk::*; }` but still this also throws `duplicate lang item in crate 'std'` error, [have a look here for further error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59388952/how-to-solve-substrate-duplicate-lang-item-in-crate-std-which-myexternalcra)

Comment: yes, you are right. I got :        
`error[E0463]: can't find crate for `panic_abort` `
and      
` error[E0152]: duplicate lang item in crate `std` (which `blst` depends on): `panic_impl`. `

Is there a solution trough link you sent me?

Comment: for solution they have suggested to [`write or update crate which support no_std`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59389341/14311968)

Comment: hmm.. i dont like that.. i hope there might be some other solution...

Comment: sadly there is no other solution @NikolaBozin